# Sorting a 2d Arrays with 3 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array which looks something like this

```
var arr= [
    [#145, "Pepsi", 3],
    [#147, "Limca", 3],
    [#134, "Budweiser", 1],
    [#132, "Heineken", 1]
    [#112, "Blackdog", 2]
    [#144, "Sprite", 3]
]
```

How can I sort this to

```
var arr= [        
    [#134, "Budweiser", 1],
    [#132, "Heineken", 1]
    [#112, "Blackdog", 2]
    [#144, "Sprite", 3]
    [#145, "Pepsi", 3],
    [#147, "Limca", 3],
]
```

The sorting is based on the last element in the array . i.e. The number.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/LFRhs/1/) to demonstrate what I tried.

An ideal solution would be one that uses the custom `arr.sort` function in JS. However I don't know how to use this function with 3 elements in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a[2] - b[2];
});
```

**P.S.**: I would recommend using an object, instead of array in that case.

Comment: @MarsOne if you are learning something new - the question is not stupid :)